# erro no fuso horario indy10 delphi

Tags: delphi, email, indy-10

tenho uma tela que envia email usando o Indy10 porem ele envia com o fuso horário errado.
Ele esta enviando o email sempre com 2 horas de atraso, ou seja, se envio as 17:00 ele marca no email como enviado as 15:00.
Verifiquei em varios sites mas o que mais parece correto seria recompilar o componente, mas o mesmo e bem complicado de compilar, sempre dando erros que falta configurações ou parâmetros de compilação.
Se eu tentar chamar a propriedade da classe a mesma "trava" a compilação do delphi.

Ex. Fri, 11 Nov 2016 12:36:40 +0000 (retirado da propriedade do email).

Porem todo o resto esta certo...
Tentei recompila esse componente mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Amigo, precisamos de mais detalhes. Qual o horário do servidor da aplicação. Qual a rotina que você usa para montar e mandar o e-mail? Propriedade do e-mail? Você quer dizer do arquivo `.eml`?  Essas informações vão nos ajudar a lhe ajudar.

Comment: opa, desculpe pela falta de infos, mas acabei achando onde.
pois ele não passa o valor do GMT -3 (Santa Catarina) para enviar o email com a hora atual.
ele envia via SMTP do nosso ofice365.
Agora estou vendo para compilar o componente do Indy 10 com o ajuste correto.

Comment: Legal.... se funcionar posta aí. Abç.

Comment: Sem sucesso amigo não funcionou, nem mesmo chamando o parametro da classe.

Comment: Como mencionei, você pode por favor postar como está o seu código (_editar a pergunta_)? Obrigado.